# How can I fix a stuck NFS without rebooting server?

Tags: 18.04, mount, nfs, umount

**My environment:**

I have three servers in my studio. Server A is an NFS server, server B and C are NFS clients.

Server B and C mount `A:/raid/data` on local `/data`. SELinux is disabled, `ufw` is not installed, `iptables` is default. And there is a layer-2 switch without any connection limit to the three servers.

**What I found:**

This morning I tried to execute `ls /data` on server B, and after about 5 mins, there was not any output.

When I connected to server C, and tried to execute `ls /data`, it worked normally.

**What I tried:**

I executed the commands listed above, and all of them were stuck without any output.

```bsh
df -Th
df
ls /
fuser -m -v /data
```

I tried to execute `umount -f /data`, it said `device is busy`.

I tried ping server A on server B, it responded with low latency.

**What I need:**

Is there any solution which doesn't involve rebooting the server? And what causes this problem? How can I avoid it?